# Is a bad pratice to use long method name in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following service class in Ruby:

```
class EnableUserMatriculations

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def call!
    matriculations_that_current_user_is_matriculated_and_confirmed.each do |matriculation|
      matriculation.enable!
    end
  end


  private

  def matriculations_that_current_user_is_matriculated_and_confirmed
    # some logic to search user.matriculations that must be enabled
  end
end
```

I would like to know if methods with long names is a bad pratice?

I don't like to use comments.

Please, give me opinions about this.

Comment: "I dont like to use comments." why? if there's a bad practice, it's to not like using comments.

Comment: Class names also don't often contain verbs.

Comment: I'm trying to follow these approachs:
(no comments) => https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3250-clarity-over-brevity-in-variable-and-method-names

(service name with verb) => http://blog.sundaycoding.com/blog/2014/11/25/my-take-on-services-in-rails/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". Questions soliciting opinions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename this method but not only because of length. You are tying the logic in the method name itself, e.g. looking for matriculations that are matriculated and confirmed. What if over time there is another case you need to handle, such as matriculations that are not processed or some such? Or what you need handle only matriculations which are just confirmed? Instead of just changing the logic inside of one method, now you need to change logic and rename methods, which is bug prone. You don't want `call!` containing the logic over which matriculations it should enable which it is because of the logic contained in the method name itself.

In this case, I change your long method name to something like

```
def matriculations_ready_to_enable
  user.matriculations.matriculated.confirmed
end
```

Then add those scope methods onto your Matriculation model. You likely would want to have a separate method on user versus `user.matriculations.matriculated.confirmed`, but this makes it clear what kind of matriculations are required, and keeps that information contained to just one part of your code.

Regarding the length itself, Ruby generally favors shorter method names versus longer ones, but also favors using complete words versus abbreviations, e.g. `def destroy_matriculations` vs `def dstry_matriculations`.

Comment: Thanks for response. In my case, the logic that will determinate what matriculations must be enabled depends on another model informations, like Invoice, Payments... For this reason I keep this logic on especific ServiceClass. This is wrong?

Comment: No, that's totally fine to keep the logic in this specific service class. I was suggesting keeping the logic in that one method, versus the method name itself.

Comment: I'm also wondering if "ready to enable" is redundant as "ready" might suffice, or given the simplicity of this method, if it's even necessary.

Comment: I agree with that, even just `ready_matriculations` or just `ready` if this method will never be used outside of the service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a bad practice. It is good to have names that describes what they do but when they become too long they make the code very hard to read. In this case you already are in the scope of a `UserMatriculations` so you can easily remove the first two words from your method to be just `current_user_is_matriculated_and_confirmed`. The leading two words don't add much to the name anyway. I try to think of names that relate to the context they exist in. If the names get too long it may also tell me something useful about the complexity of the context.

(Also I would say that these advices apply to most if not all programming languages - not just Rails.)

Comment: I think `current_user_is_matriculated_and_confirmed` implies a Boolean result versus returning a collection of matriculations.

Comment: @chrismanderson I interpreted it that way too, it implies a logical test. That it returns a scope requires careful reading of the internals.